# What is the stall speed of the Antonov An-225?

Tags: aircraft-performance, stall, antonov-225

Under certain circumstances - maximum gross weight, unaccelerated 1G flight, clean configuration (landing gear up and flaps)? Indicated airspeed (KIAS) of course.

Comment: We might need someone who can read the Russian POH to answer this.  The closest I found was a no-flaps landing speed of [295 km/h](https://gelio.livejournal.com/193025.html).  Flapped takeoff, at least 240 km/h.